# AWS CloudFormation: AWS::Events::Rule - InputTemplate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses

I'm building a AWS CloudFormation file, and I'm stuck in the `AWS::Events::Rule` service. I'm trying to make a rule that will send out an email to developers for every stage of a CodePipeline. This is the whole file:

```
{
    "PipelineWebpageAccessStageNotification": {
        "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
        "Properties": {
            "Description": "Send out notifications to developers about the CodePipeline stages status for the websites.",
            "Name": "codepipeline-webpage_access",
            "RoleArn": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["PipelineWebpageAccessStageNotificationRole", "Arn" ] },
            "EventPattern": {
                "source": [
                    "aws.codepipeline"
                ],
                "detail-type": [
                    "CodePipeline Stage Execution State Change"
                ],
                "detail": {
                    "pipeline": [
                        { "Ref": "PipelineWebpageAccess" }
                    ],
                    "state": [
                        "FAILED",
                        "CANCELED",
                        "RESUMED",
                        "SUCCEEDED",
                        "STARTED"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "State": "ENABLED",
            "Targets": [
                {
                    "Arn": { "Ref": "SNSTopic" },
                    "Id": "SNS",
                    "InputTransformer": {
                        "InputPathsMap": {
                            "pipeline": "$.detail.pipeline",
                            "stage": "$.detail.stage",
                            "state": "$.detail.state"
                        },
                        "InputTemplate": "Hello Human, This message is related to the CodePipeline: <pipeline>. Bellow are some details: \r\n\r\n - Stage: <stage>\r\n - Status: <state>\r\n\r\n Thank you for reading, Enjoy your existence."
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is with `InputTemplate`. CloudFormation tells me to send a String. Which I'm doing... Turns out that you actually have to send a string containing JSON. OK, so I did that as I did in other other places, for example you pass a string with JSON when you build a dashboard in CloudWatch. That works without a problem. But here - it keeps failing.

The interesting thing, is that the same issue happens in the AWS Dashboard.

I did talk with AWS Tach Support, and they also have no idea how to solve this, they did provided some approaches to try, but none worked.

They told me they are going to ask the team that is responsible for this part of AWS, but I don't have high hopes.

## Question

If you had the same problem and some how figure it out, we'd be grateful for the solution :)

Comment: The documentation is strange for this, reading the link below your `InputTemplate` should be something like this: `"InputTemplate": "\"Hello Human, This message is related to the CodePipeline: <pipeline>. Bellow are some details: \r\n\r\n - Stage: <stage>\r\n - Status: <state>\r\n\r\n Thank you for reading, Enjoy your existence.\""`. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=798687

Answer (score 0):

It must be a valid string inside AWS, not only at `JSON` template. So `InputTemplate` must be like this in `JSON` CloudFormation (note escaped quotes):

```
"InputTemplate": "\"your text here <placeholders>\""
```

For `YAML` it should be like this:

```
InputTemplate: |
    "Line 1 <placeholders>."
    "Line 2 <placeholders>."
```

When I created it from console it shows me like below:

```
Input Transformer: {"InputPathsMap":{"state":"$.detail.state"},"InputTemplate":"\"bla <state>\""}
```

Comment: This is a solution that dose not work. I mean it dose work, but it won't work with the new line characters. And if you remove the new line chars, then the email actually starts with a `"`.

Comment: For YAML I had to add an extra new line between each line.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular problem, we ended up sending not a JSON object but a single, doublequoted string, which also valid JSON. Then it does allow you to use placeholders inside of the string, suitable for composing an email body or subject.

So our email lambda takes the following argument:

```
"recipient@email.org\nSubject line with <placeholder>\nMessage line 1 with <placeholder>\nMessage line N"
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirming that the comment by azize is correct, alhought the \r\n did not work for me, they just shown up in the notification. Here is what worked for me.

JSON:

```
"InputTemplate": "\"Hello Human, This message is related to the CodePipeline: <pipeline>. Details:  - Stage: <stage> - Status: <state> Thank you for reading, Enjoy your existence.\""
```

YAML:

```
InputTemplate: '"Hello Human, This message is related to the CodePipeline: <pipeline>. Details:  - Stage: <stage> - Status: <state> Thank you for reading, Enjoy your existence."'
```